# Need DB2 OLEDB Driver / ODBC Driver

Tags: database, db2

I am trying to establish a connection between excel and db2. I am able to successfully query and retrieve data from my DB.

I am using the below connection string

```
Provider=IBMDADB2;Database=RQAPROJ;HOSTNAME=jebal asu;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;PORT=50000;uid=administrator;pw d=we"
```

The issue now is that I have DB2 installed on my machine and the connection works perfect, however when I try from a Machine which does not have db2 installed I get an error straightaway that the Provider is not found.

I understand that DB2 drivers needs to be installed on the client machine as well.
I had been trying in Google to get my hands on DB2 OLE DB drivers so that I can package it along with my excel tool but I am not able to find it for download.

I am not sure if there is any other way to get this done, so can anyone point me to a download location for these drivers?

Answer (score 1):

URL for downloading IBM Data Server client packages:
[Fix Packs by Version](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27016878)

To get the provider, you need (at a minimum) the *Driver for ODBC and CLI*.  This won't provide front end tooling, but that may be OK for you.  Alternatively you can download the (larger) *Runtime Client* or the full *Client*.

Comment: Ian,

Thank you for your input.. I am downloading them right away... Do you have any idea how to package that with excel and How do I call them on the systems that does not have the provider... should I package the runtime client and do an installation ??